# How to access private C/C++ symbols android

Tags: c++, api, native, private, symbols

is anyone knows how to access private c/c++ symbols used by android api ? For example like native_setRotate function inside Matrix class. And I want to be able to see how it implemented and coming from which header files ? How to do that ? I need it to implemented the logic function into my native jni as build from scratch would be too complicated.

Comment: You cannot access private members, that's why they were made `private`.

Comment: But, that's not what I mean. I saw a blog when googling, we can using private c/c++ from android api itself. So, I can included like #include<something.h>, but what is something.h that's I need to know. I know for the next google not allowed us to dynamic linking against them, but at least I can see the code to copy the logic. Thanks

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Well, there *is* always the [public_cast](https://web.archive.org/web/20121030234734/http://byuu.org/articles/programming/public_cast) option ;-) Not that I would recommend it though...

Comment: @JesperJuhl Shudder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access private members, but if you just want to find the source code of it, google can help you, as the android source code is open source.

[This is where](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android/graphics/Matrix.cpp) the JNI bindig is defined, you can trace it back from there.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I'm looking for. You really saves my life. Thank you.